# Creating an Interface for JUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, testcase

I started a project using TDD.

I have few `parsers` that implementing the same interface.

each one of them have a different implementation of this specific interface.

While testing them i just repeat again and again the same tests for each one of them.

was wondering if it is possible to create an interface of all of the `JUnits` while implementing it i will just get it as:

```
@Override
@Test
public void testMethodA()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
@Test
public void testMethodB()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Instead of copy and past every time and create the test deceleration manually?
as well when the class interface change , i need to add to each of of the JUnit the test and etc..

Bottom line,

I want to auto generate an empty test-case for each class by implementing and interface which there i would declarer on the common parser tests. Is there a way to do that using `eclipse` ?

Comment: This isn't 100% clear. Are you saying you want to auto-generate an empty test-case for each class?

Comment: You can simply define a base class containing all the tests common to all the parsers, and define a subclass for each parser implementation, whose sole job is to create the parser to test.

Comment: Yeah , i want to auto generate an empty  test-case for each class by implementing and interface which there i would declarer on the common parser tests.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you're using a good IDE (IntelliJ falls into this category), you can get it to auto-implement an interface.

Comment: is there any way to do it in eclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I writing integration test cases using JUnit 4 and Selenium WebDriver for my company project.I face the same issue like you.So I create one of **base test case**  that extends `junit.framework.TestCase` and write all common methods for all junit classes. See sample implementation,

```
public class BaseTestCase extends TestCase {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
         //Do something.
     }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //Do something.
    }

    protected boolean isElementPresent() {
         //Do something.
         return true;   
    }
    ....

}
```

And I extends that **base test case** on all of my specific JUnit classes.See

```
 public class LoginTest extends BaseTestCase {
       ...
 }

 public class FooTest extends BaseTestCase {
       ...
 }
```

I just share my way to you.It is not sure the solution what you need.In eclipse there is no plugins or features for generating ready made JUnit test cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot , better then nothing :)